# Extracting similar data from dictionary and putting into a new list or array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 5 keys that each key refers to a list (a CSV file with 100 rows and 5 columns). Each row of the list points to a data of a person. I would like to extract the similar row of each list and put into a new list or an array. So at the end I should have 100 lists/array such that each list/array contains a user’s data. And then I want to do some experiments like machine learning and so on.

This is my example:

```
My_dict={0,1,2,3}

0={id,var1,var2,var3
    User1,med,high,low
    User2,med,low,low
    …,…,..,..,
    User100,hih,low,med}

1={id,var1,var2,var3
    User1,high,med,low
    User2,high,med,low
    …,…,..,..,
    User100,low,low,med}

2={id,var1,var2,var3
    User1,low,med,low
    User2,med,med,low
    …,…,..,..,
    User100,med,low,med}
```

So I want to have a list of lists or array of arrays that I can experiment with. Something like this:

```
User1={id,var1,var2,var3
    User1,med,high,low
    User1,high,med,low
    User1,low,med,low
}

User2={d,var1,var2,var3
    User2,med,high,low
    User2,high,med,low
    User2,low,med,low
}
```

Comment: I am a bit new in python and looking for a simple code to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

```
input_data = {"0":[["U1","med","low","high"],["U2","low","low","high"],["U3","high","low","high"]], "1": [["U1","med","low","high"],["U2","low","low","high"],["U3","high","low","high"]]}


# Assuming that above kind of data you have then below dict will be your output

users_dict = dict()
for key, users in input_data.iteritems():
    for user in users:
        users_dict.setdefault(user[0], []).append(user)
```

Comment: It looks something is wrong, when I print the keys after implementing the above code  print(users_dict.keys()), it gives me this result: dict_keys(['U', 'm', 'h', 'l', 'E', 'n', 'A', 'C', 'L']), which is not what I needed. The other thing is this code is only for one list. Since I have a multiple list in my dictionary like this:My_dict={0,1,2,3},  I need to run it through the all lists and extract all users data in to different dictionary e.g., U1,.., U100.

Comment: input_data can have as many keys as you want, current just for example I added only one key '0'. can you try now, I have added one more key in input data

Comment: I tried this code works well, but the output is the first line of each key "only Header" that in my example are e.g., [id,var1,var2,var3]. However my dictionary e.g "0" has something like this "0":[["Id_User","V1","V2",V3";                                                                                                                                                                 "U1","med","low","high"                                                                                                "U2","low","med","high" ]. Consider CSV file with header and multiple rows.

Comment: At the end how can I convert them into different arrays that I can use them for my experiment like machine learning, etc.

Comment: sorry but the output for above code i.e. users_dict looks like {'U1': [['U1', 'med', 'low', 'high'], ['U1', 'med', 'low', 'high']], 'U3': [['U3', 'high', 'low', 'high'], ['U3', 'high', 'low', 'high']], 'U2': [['U2', 'low', 'low', 'high'], ['U2', 'low', 'low', 'high']]} which is for every guest there will be a list of lists

Comment: I will try to look carefully and will let you know.

Comment: I re-checked it again, the output for above example for Users.dict is : {"I":['id','id','id','id'],"V1":['v1','v1','v1','v1'], "V2";['v2','v2','v2','v2'],"V3";['v3','v3','v3','v3']}. I think something is wrong in the loop. because the dictionary contains 4 lists which is the number of variables in the list. In fact it should contain exactly the same thing that you mentioned.

Comment: output will have keys which will be equal to total no of unique users, and corresponding to every key there will be a list of user data(again a list).

Comment: is above answer anyhow proved to be helpful or do you need further breakdown.

Comment: Yes , of course it was useful such that I changed a bit the loop using the same function ".setdefault "and right now works. Thank you.

Comment: always ready to help, please upvote and accept as the correct answer